# Python 3: Unroll arguments from tuple

Tags: python, arguments, tuples

Given a Python tuple `t = v1, v2, v3` is there a utility to unpack these so that given:

```
def foo(v1,v2,v3): pass
```

Instead of this:

```
foo(t[0],t[1],t[2])
```

You can do this:

```
foo(unpack(t))
```

I'd like to know of any such utility available for tuples and/or lists.

Sincere thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yep.  You can use the unpacking operator (`'*'`)

```
foo(*t)
```

Note that this works if t is a `list`, `tuple`, or even a generator

---

There's an analogous way to pass arguments to functions with keywords using the `**` operator on mapping objects (typically dictionaries):

```
def foo(key=None,foo=None):
    pass #...

foo(**{key:1,foo:2})
```

Answer (score 2):

[Unpack](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) the argument list:

```
foo(*(v1, v2, v3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `*args` argument passing:

```
foo(*t)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def foo(v1, v2, v3):
...     print(v1, v2, v3)
...
>>> t = 1, 2, 3
>>> foo(*t)
1 2 3
```